# Import class in java

Tags: java

I have three classes main, A,B,C.
From Main I am calling method of class A and in class A we are calling method of class B.
Now From main i want to call the method of class B in class C without declaring the object of class A again as i declared in class B, so that i can get the data which i have saved. is this possible in java.         `

Main class:

```java
UserMenu y= new UserMenu();
y.Umenu();
```

Class A:

```java
public availablestock item = new availablestock();
item.show();
```

Class C:

I want to call the show function again is it possible to display the data of Class A in class C.

Comment: You can create B in main and either give to A and/or C in the constructor, as a set() method or as public property.  Although at that point, you could just call the method in B because you already have B.  Another option is adding a method to A to return a reference to B and hand that off to C.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.